# how to display a string as a block of text in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function that returns a string. I want to write this string to an html page, but in a block-of-text format where I can specify the width. I'm currently using a read-only `textarea`, but I'm sure there's a much better way. How would I do this?

Example:

String returned from javascript function:
`The dog was lazy in the sun.`

On the html page:

```
The dog was  
lazy in the  
sun.
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, I wasn't being clear enough. 
This javascript function could return any string, I don't know what it could return.
So inside my html, I would do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" />  
    document.write(functionCall());  
</script>
```

but I would like to format this like in the example above.
Unfortunately, wrapping this in `<div>` tags with the `width` attribute doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text, width, container;

width = "200px";        // set this to whatever you like
text = some_function();

// you can create a <div id="text-container"></div> in your
// HTML wherever you want the text to show up, or you can
// the JavaScript just create it at the bottom of the page

container = document.getElementById("text-container");
if(!container) {
    container = document.createElement("div");
    container.id = "text-container";
    document.body.appendChild(container);
}

container.style.width=width;
container.innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Good but you need to handle the issue of the body tag may not be defined and hence see https://www.vitamindev.com/javascript/why-is-document-body-null/

Comment: @user3599207 I don't think Stackoverflow answers are intended to be complete end-to-end solutions. They're meant to be examples to point the requester in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Place the text in a `<pre>` tag, after all, it stands for pre-formatted text.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

You can then use CSS to control the width of the element:

```
pre {
    width: 100px;
}
```

That way you could alternately add the breaks in the string itself and add it to the `<pre>` tag and it would be already formatted (and you wouldn't need the width).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by fixind the width like in div as offex said

`<div style="width:200px"></div>`

or

a table with a width on it

`<table width="200px"></table>`